# How do you get event notifications back to the main program class of a Java console app?

Tags: java, events, console-application

I'm coming to Java from C#, and I'm really just trying to figure out how to do things in Java world.  I'm running Java 8 in IntelliJ IDEA.  I found [this](https://scatteredcode.wordpress.com/2011/11/24/from-c-to-java-events/) explaining events in Java as basically being hand-made through manual registration and an interface method call.  The code example has enough problems that I assume it was never compiled.  After cleaning that up a bit I have this:

Interface MetronomeEvent:

```
public interface MetronomeEvent {
    void Tick(Date tickDate);
}
```

Class EventFiringSource:

```
public class EventFiringSource {

    // Our collection of classes that are subscribed as listeners of our
    protected List<MetronomeEvent> _listeners=new ArrayList();

    // Method for listener classes to register themselves
    public void addMetronomeEventListener(MetronomeEvent listener)
    {
        _listeners.add(listener);
    }

    // "fires" the event
    protected void fireMetronomeEvent()
    {
        if (_listeners != null && !_listeners.isEmpty())
        {
            for (MetronomeEvent e:_listeners)
            {
                e.Tick(new Date());
            }
        }
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        fireMetronomeEvent();
    }
}
```

Main console application:

```
public class MainApp implements MetronomeEvent {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventFiringSource source = new EventFiringSource();
        source.addMetronomeEventListener(this); // Adds itself as a listener for the event
        source.Start();
    }

    public void Tick(Date tickDate)
    {
        System.out.println(tickDate.toString());
    }
}
```

The one remaining error is `source.addMetronomeEventListener(this);` where the compiler complains that it cannot reference `MyApp.this` from a static context.  That makes sense, but I don't see any way then that I could, after implementing the MetronomeEvent interface on the main program class, actually pass it to `source.addMetronomeEventListener()` for registration.  Is it impossible to directly register the main program class for events?  Am I supposed to create and register a Listener class that implements MetronomeEvent and will act on behalf of the main application?  Like this?

```
public class Listener implements MetronomeEvent {
    public void Tick(Date tickDate){
        System.out.println(tickDate.toString());
    }
}
```

And then:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventFiringSource source = new EventFiringSource();
    Listener l=new Listener();
    source.addMetronomeEventListener(l); // Adds another object to listen on behalf of main()
    source.Start();
}
```

Comment: Static methods belong to the class, not objects (instances of the class). `this` is used to refer "*the current object*", and since non-static methods must be called from an object, it's possible to have a "current object" (the object you are calling it from); you can use `this` in non-static methods. But in the case of static methods, which can be called directly from the class and doesn't require an object to be called, there is no way to determine which object should be referenced. Since your interface has only 1 method, you could use a lambda to pass in the code you want.

Comment: `source.addMetronomeEventListener(new MainApp());`? You also might like to have a read through [Code Conventions for the Java TM Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html), it will make it easier for people to read your code and for you to read others

Comment: Thank you Vince.  You led me right where I needed to be.  I'm going to add an answer with solutions in code, but if you would like to add your comment as an answer I will select it as The Answer since you solved the problem and should get credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not about events, it's about `main()` and static methods in general.

I would suggest writing your main() as

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new MainApp(args).execute();
}
```

This way you're immediately jumping from static function world into object-oriented world.

Comment: I assume, since the Executor interface method execute(Runnable r) has a parameter, that execute in your example is just an instance method that I define in MainApp that contains the application code.  Correct?

Comment: Yes. You can name anything you like, may be runApplication() is better. As long as you get away from static methods

Answer (score 0):

Based on Vince Emigh's comment/answer I was led [to this Oracle doc on lamda expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) and to [this one on method references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html).  I've found 3 ways to do this so far.

1) Anonymous class:

```
    source.addMetronomeEventListener(
            new MetronomeEvent() {
                @Override
                public void Tick(Date tickDate) {
                    System.out.println("anonymous class:");
                    System.out.println(tickDate.toString());

                }
            }
    ); // Adds itself as a listener for the event
```

2) Lambda expression:

```
source.addMetronomeEventListener(d -> System.out.println("lambda:\n"+d.toString()));
```

3) Method reference, which is the closest to what I am accustomed to.  A method is defined in the main class:

```
public static void processTick(Date tickDate){
    System.out.println("method reference:");
    System.out.println(tickDate.toString());
}
```

...and then in the body of main() it is added as an event handler like this:

```
source.addMetronomeEventListener(MainApp::processTick);
```